# Neovim Scss variables - go to definition

Tags: sass, neovim

Is there a way I can goto definition (gd) when my cursor is on scss variable?

I know i can grep with telescope but that’s not what i want.

I have nvim cmp (kickstart nvim) and cssls language server installed.

Filetype is correctly recognized as scss and cssls is attached to the buffer.

Tried some cmp plugins …